# How to fix the button position in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm making a website and I have one problem: the middle button is located differently from the other buttons. Here's what the source code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:darkblue;font-family:franklin gothic"><b><i>DAVE J'S OFFICIAL WEBSITE</b></i></h1>

    <button style="text-align:center;color:slateblue;background:lightgreen;font-family:courier new;height:50px;width:75px;font-size:17px"><b><i>HOME</i></b></button>
    <button style="text-align:center;color:slateblue;background:lightgreen;font-family:courier new;height:50px;width:75px;font-size:17px;position:relative;"><b><i>SOCIAL MEDIA</i></b></button>
    <button style="text-align:center;color:slateblue;background:lightgreen;font-family:courier new;height:50px;width:75px;font-size:17px"><b><i>BLOG</i></b></button>
</div>
</html>
```

Can you please tell me where's the problem? Thank you for help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I didn't realize that the text inside a button behaves that way. Seems to have a life of its own.

A couple of errors to begin with:

- missing opening div
- `b` and `i` reversed in h1

Fix:

- add `flex` to wrapping div.

```css
h1 {
  color: darkblue;
  font-family: franklin gothic;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

button,
.btn {
  background: lightgreen;
  color: slateblue;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<h1>DAVE J'S OFFICIAL WEBSITE</h1>

<div>
  <button>HOME</button>
  <button style="position:relative;">SOCIAL MEDIA</button>
  <button>BLOG</button>
</div>
```